# Java ServerSocket and Android LocalServerSocket

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have implemented my own android service as follows

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    private Server mServer; 
    private LocalServerSocket server;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        mServer = new Server();
        mServer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if(server != null){
            try {
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "exception in server close");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    class Server extends Thread {
    @Override
        public void run() {
             try {
                server = new LocalServerSocket("my.socket");
                while (true) {
                    LocalSocket receiver;
                    try{
                        receiver = server.accept();
                    }catch(SocketException e){
                        Log.d(TAG, "SocketException");
                        break;
                    }
                    catch(IOException e){
                        Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (receiver != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got Data in receiver");
                    }
                    receiver.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "one more");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, if my LocalServerSocket is blocking in accept(), then a call to server.close() in OnDestroy() will not throw a SocketException. Hence, next time I start the service, I get "address already in use exception". If instead of LocalServerSocket, I use java.net.Socket, then i get the required behavior. I would like to know why LocalServerSocket behaves differently from Java Sockets. In my case, how do I come out of the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and "solved" it this way. The thread run() method is checking for "!isInterrupted()". The method "stopSocketServer()" which I added to my Listener-Thread  marks the thread for interrupt() and then made a connect request to itself to trigger the accept() method.

```
/**
 * Executed if thread is started.
 */
public void run() {

    try {
        // leave while loop if thread is marked for interrupt.
        while (!isInterrupted()) { 
            LocalSocket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            if (!isInterrupted()) {
                threadPool.execute(new ClientProcessor(clientSocket));
            }
        } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!isInterrupted()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "socket listener terminated", e);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
            if (threadPool != null) {
                threadPool.shutdownNow();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "socket listener stopped");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
} 

public void stopSocketServer() {
    if (serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            // mark thread as interrupted
            interrupt();

            // now send connect request to myself to trigger leaving accept()
            LocalSocket ls = new LocalSocket();
            ls.connect(serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
            ls.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "stopSocketServer failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted it looks like your `LocalServerSocket server` will remain `null` forever and `onDestroy()` won't close it. Also, closing the socket normally shouldn't throw IOException - but the `accept()` will do so if the socket is closed concurrently.

Comment: So do you mean I should create another thread to close the socket? I tried that, but the problem remained. As long as I am waiting on accept(), I am unable to use the address again! Is there any work around for my code?